# Converting a Prototype ajax request to jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I could use some help converting this ajax request to jQuery.  The main things tripping me up is the evalJS: param.
Here is the original:

```
var fields = $$('#sign_in *[name^="session"]');

    new Ajax.Request($F('consumer_login_url'), {
        asynchronous: true,
        evalJS: true,
        method: 'post',
        parameters: Form.serializeElements(fields),
        onCreate: function(){
            $('one_click_wrap').addClassName('loading');
        },
        onSuccess: function() {
            $('one_click_wrap').removeClassName('loading');
            return oneClickSuccess();
        },
    });
```

Here is where I am stuck at:

```
 var fields = $('#sign_in *[name^="session"]');
     $.Ajax({
        url: 'consumer_login_url',
        async: true,
        method: 'post',
        data: $(fields).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#one_click_wrap').addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#one_click_wrap').removeClass('loading');
            return oneClickSuccess();
        },
    });
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the dataType argument and set it to "script", described [on this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Other notes:

- The method is lowercase ajax, not $.Ajax
- You don't need to set async to true (true is the default)
- Per the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), it's typically easier to select the form tag for the serialize method.